# Is there a way to animate a morph between different fonts?

Tags: shape-keys, text-object

I want to make an animation where the font changes into another in a smooth way.

Example: https://youtu.be/rtKbMZqnYFE?t=10s

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

[SVG of second example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jcg2rmvaugz2j1x/font_morph.svg?dl=0)

Yes, with [this add-on](https://youtu.be/XMimQfQR_ss) you can do this (and more). 
[image]
Or, if you use 2d curves:
[image]

Comment: How did you make the second example?

Comment: In the second example the curves are 2d.. so they are filled. And you can ensure a smoother transition by matching the nodes (<kbd>F2</kbd> and double click on path in inkscape) in source and destination shapes in the SVG from where you are importing the paths. I am also attaching the SVG I used for this example.